# Using Lambda function to create prefixes/folder like Athena when doing query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

When you run an AWS Athena Query, it typically stores the output in a specific order in an S3 bucket. For example: `S3::BucketName//AWSLogs/2024/03/24/file.csv`

I want to achieve the same using a Lambda function when the query is executed every day. When the Lambda function runs, I want it to create a new prefix:

```
S3::BucketName//AWSLogs/2024/03/new_day/file.csv
S3::BucketName//AWSLogs/2024/new_month/new_day/file.csv
```

- **New_day**: Create a prefix/folder each day.
- **New_month**: Create a prefix/folder each month.

Is it possible to do this? If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I wrote a Lambda function to do it, however it does not work the same as Athena.

Comment: "Create a prefix/folder " Unlike a traditional hierarchical filesystem, S3 is nonhierarchical object storage.  "Folder"s do not need to exist as individual entities for objects to be stored "within" them.  It's just a prefix to their name.  The S3 web console confuses this as it allows you to "Create" a "Folder" that exist in and of itself, but that's really just an empty object that exists solely for the purpose of allowing the web console to navigate "into" it.  TLDR: Don't create "folders", just create objects with the prefxes you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the query is executed every day"? What query are you referring to? Is this a query you trigger from the Lambda function? How is the CSV file being created?